# Data from logic app to function and send to Fortnox api

Tags: c#, json, api, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

In logic apps i have json data:

```
{
  "amount": "116159.90",

  "date": "2021-11-04",

  "fee": "3412.30"
}
```

**Step 1:**
I want to send this data to azure function

**Step 2:**
I want to put the json data (amount, date and fee), so i can send it as C# code to api endpoint so it looks like the code below. The rest of the data is hardcoded.

See documentation here (Create Voucher C#) https://developer.fortnox.se/documentation/resources/vouchers/

---

```
VoucherConnector connector = new VoucherConnector();
List<VoucherRow> rows = new List<VoucherRow>();

rows.Add(new VoucherRow() {

    Account = "2480",
    Description = "Checkräkningskredit, kortfristig",
    **Debit = "AMOUNT",**
    Credit = "0"
});

rows.Add(new VoucherRow() {

    Account = "6092",
    Description = "Shopify Fee",
    **Debit = "FEE",**
    Credit = "0"
});

rows.Add(new VoucherRow() {

    Account = "1509",
    Description = "Shopify fordran",
    Debit = "0",
    **Credit = "(=AMOUNT+FEE)"**
});

Voucher result = connector.Create(new Voucher() {

    ****TransactionDate = "DATE",****
    Description = "Inbetalning Shopify",
    VoucherRows = rows,
    VoucherSeries = "A"
});
```

Comment: From your question, it is not clear what specific part of the process you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Because the data is in json format located in the logic app, so my question is how do I make the json data accessible for the function to use because the code is in C#, all the code is already done, I just need to know how to put the data in respective voucherRow as in the description above. The logic app runs on a schedule so it will be diffrent data every run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following question:

> Because the data is in json format located in the logic app, so my
> question is how do I make the json data accessible for the function

By looking at your JSON data, you need to pass only 3 values: amount, date and fee. You don't really *have* to pass this data in JSON format. E.g. you could sent it to your API endpoint in a query string:

`https://example.com/over/there?amount=116159.90&date=2021-11-04&fee=3412.30`

Then you could easily get them from the [`HttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0) object:

```
string date = req.Query["date"];
```

If you do want to send JSON data to your API endpoint in the request body, you can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NuGet to [deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) it:

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
string date = data?.date;
```