Pass custom tracking ID from Logic app to Function app
I want to be able to pass the custom tracking ID to the function app. I have a logic app which calls the function app and I need to pick up the custom tracking ID so I can make use of Application Insights for a complete track of the flow from start to end.
Do any of you have an idea how to achieve this?


You cannot get tracking Id directly from trigger action to use it in next actions in workflow.
Aletrnatively, you can send tracking id to http trigger and then set the tracking id in headers and then also send it in body:

Body:
{"id":"8'}


Now, you can use the value of id in next step with triggerbody(), You can send it now to azure functions as its headers and inside the function app log its value, to get to know the tracking id. So, this is one of way to get and there is no direct way to get tracking inside the logic app in next actions. It is logged and stored In logs of Logic apps. Tracking id is only used for logging for Logic apps.
EDIT:
Alternatively,thanks @10p, you can use below lines to get tracking id and then you can send it to function as header as mentioned above:
@{trigger()?['clientTrackingId']}

@{trigger()?['trackingId']}


You can access trigger properties in your Logic App as follows:
@{trigger()?['clientTrackingId']}

@{trigger()?['trackingId']}

Example:




That didnt work for me @10p

@RithwikBojja - Added screenshots

@10p is it possible to pass this value to the function app or pick it up from the function app? That is what I am looking for. If you know how, it would be very cool :)

@Sergio The Logic App can call an Azure Function sending the data in the query or in the body of the request (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69912881/624368 for details) or indeed in the headers.
